# Conditional JS for IE doesn't work

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, header, conditional-statements

I have a very basic question (I think) but I really don't arrive to make it work. I have searched throught the web and follow some instructions but nothing. The problem is that I have a header with a conditional JS and CSS for IE, when I run this script within the IE condition it works perfect in Firefox, Safari...but when I tried it (with and without conditional) in IE7 it doesn't work. Did you know what could be?

Header (simplified)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Prueba</title>
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Reset & General CSS-->
<link href="css/reset.css" media="screen" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Specific functions -->
<script src="js/musabamba.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ie.js"></script>
<link href="/css/ie.css" media="screen" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]--> 
</head>
```

ie.js (I put a Jquery.noConflict because it cause problem with another function)

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function(){
$j(".coleccion").addClass("selected");
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it was a problem duplicating the noConflict variable. Cause I had the same in musamba.js so it's make a noConflict conflict :)

ie.js

```
/* JS for IE */
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j(".coleccion").addClass("selected");
});
```